# Laravel 5.6.15 does not want to accept my post requests

Tags: php, laravel, postman, crud

I wrote a route to accept post request:

```
Route::post('/imageprocessor', 'ImageProcessorController@processImage');
```

and with Postman I sent a request post to `http://queue_processor.local/imageprocessor` getting back:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException
```

and response headers:

```
Cache-Control →no-cache, private
Connection →keep-alive
Content-Type →text/html; charset=UTF-8
Server →nginx/1.13.3
Transfer-Encoding →chunked
allow →GET, HEAD
date →Fri, 13 Apr 2018 12:57:17 GMT
```

while my route list is:

```
+--------+----------+----------------+------+------------------------ 
------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI            | Name | Action                                                     
| Middleware |
+--------+----------+----------------+------+------------------------ 
------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /              |      | Closure                                                    
| web    |
|        | POST     | imageprocessor |      | 
App\Http\Controllers\ImageProcessorController@processImage | web        
|
+--------+----------+----------------+------+------------------------ 
------------------------------------+------------+
```

what's wrong?

Comment: Hello, have you checked if it fails in csrf protection?

Comment: How can I check it?

Comment: what's the form method ?

Comment: You could initially comment  \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class in app/Http/Kernlel.php @  protected $middlewareGroups and try again with postman

Comment: we can check your route.php complete

Comment: @DimitrisKontoulis I have commented the token class verification but still the same

Comment: Could you try to run the request in laravel's own php server?
php artisan serve
request postman @ http://localhost:8000/imageprocessor

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow the sending of Cross-Origin Resource Sharing headers
You may want to connect this library
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors